# How to set proxy in android while using mobile hotspot or usb tethering?

Tags: android, proxy, mitmproxy

I was trying to setup `mitmproxy` to see the API requests that apps on my phone make. As the docs say I have to add proxy URL in the android phone. But as far I can find if the Android phone is connected via Wifi it can get the proxy settings. But I don't have a Wifi router to connect to Wifi. I only have Internet on my Android which I use on my Linux computer using Wifi hotspot or USB tethering.

Is their anyway I can get those proxy settings when I use Wifi hotspot or USB tethering?

Comment: You can try [PCAP remote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.egorovandreyrm.pcapremote). It does not use a proxy configuration, instead it works as a local VPN (client and server are on the Android device). However this set-up does not work with mitmproxy.